# Using TabBarView with DraggableScrollableSheet in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am developing a city travel guide application for my project. In this project, I have page like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFl0n.jpg)

In this page, I want to make the container with red border scrollable vertically until green line with `DraggableScrollableSheet` . And also I want to add `TabBarView` to the same container and scroll horizontally.
But I can not handle, encountered with many render errors.
How  can i fix this?

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:after_layout/after_layout.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final double _expandedBottomSheetBottomPosition = 0;
  final townimage;
  const CategoryScreen({Key key, this.townimage}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CategoryScreen createState() => _CategoryScreen(
        townimage: this.townimage,
      );
}

class _CategoryScreen extends State<CategoryScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, AfterLayoutMixin<CategoryScreen> {
  var townimage;
  _CategoryScreen({this.townimage});
  double _bottomSheetBottomPosition = -330;
  bool isCollapsed = false;
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(elevation: 0, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
                tag: "image" + townimage,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "images/photos/turkey.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
              bottom: _bottomSheetBottomPosition,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _tabBar(),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 3.0),
                      color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
                          height: 90,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Historical Places",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 28.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                          child: _clipsWidget(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _clipsWidget() {
    return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
        height: 250,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.account_balance_rounded),
              Text("I want to add TabBarView to this area"),
              Text(
                "Some Future Builder elements will be implemented.",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      setState(() {
        isCollapsed = true;
        _bottomSheetBottomPosition = widget._expandedBottomSheetBottomPosition;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget _tabBar() {
    return TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
        isScrollable: true,
        labelColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        tabs: [
          Container(
            height: 70,
            child: Tab(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.account_balance_rounded,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 70,
            child: Tab(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor.withOpacity(0.8),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.park,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```